# Facet_grid: change position of strip text to top and change color

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

This is my very first question. Also, I want to say that I am very new to R and ggplot2.

I want to place a label for every 'grid' to identify each category (In_motion, High_intensity ... and so on).

This is a sample of the data I'm working with.

```r
library (tidyverse)
library (ggplot2)
library (dplyr)
library (directlabels)

activity_move_3_long <- tibble(
  Day_name = factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), labels =  c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday")),
  Intensity_cat = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3), labels = c("In_motion", "High_intensity", "Moderate_intensity", "Light_intensity")),
  value = c(252, 26, 16, 211, 277, 24, 17, 236, 248, 22, 14, 212, 256, 24, 14)
)
```

This is the code of my plot

```r
ggplot(data = activity_move_3_long, aes(x = Day_name, y = value, color = Intensity_cat))+
  geom_line(aes(group = Intensity_cat), size = 1.2)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Intensity_cat), scales = 'free_y')+
  geom_dl(aes(label = Intensity_cat), method ='last.points')+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
  theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image: my plot]

- I was trying with the *annotate()* function, but not luck at all. Documentation is not being very helpful for me.
- I installed the *directlabels package* and I was able to plot inside each chart the label of the category. But I don't like how it looks and I wasn't able to change the position.
- so I was thinking to change the strip text from the right side to the top side.

**Can anyone help me solve this please?**

Comment: Try with `facet_grid(rows = vars(Intensity_cat), scales = "free_y", switch = "y")`

Comment: I did it, but not worked. the argument _switch = 'y'_ move the strip labels from the right side to the left side. I also tried _switch = 'x'_ but nothing changed.

Comment: Hm. Just to clarify. In your question title you ask for switching to the "top" while in in your post you ask for switching from the right to left?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I will edit it. I need to: change it to the top **or** delete them and use any alternative that let me place a legend in each grid for each category.

Comment: Okay. If you want to place it at the top I would go for `facet_wrap(vars(Intensity_cat), scales = "free_y", ncol = 1)`